# jQuery load( ) and switch statement not working

Tags: jquery, load, switch-statement

I have three anchor tag links  in my html with id's "switcher", "switcher-b", "switcher-c", when anchor tag "switcher" is clicked I would like to load content from a html page on my server "content.html", anchor "switcher-b" will load "content-b.html", and "switcher-c" will load "content-c.html". I also have an anchor tag id "default" when clicked will reset / unload the html pages.

I figured a switch statement would be the best way to achieve my task but it is not working... I'm not proficient with jQuery/ JavaScript but I want to learn so if any JavaScript / jQuery developers with intermediate or advance knowledge can identify what I am doing wrong in my jQuery syntax and suggest a solution with explanation I truly will appreciate it.

Thank you for viewing my post and your help.

```
 <!-- HTML code -->

     <html>

        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>AJAX Calls with jQuery load()</h1>
        <div id="switcher">
        <p><a id="switcher" href="#">Click here to fetch HTML content</a></p>
        <p><a id="switcher-b" href="#">Click here to fetch HTML content</a></p>
        <p><a id="switcher-c" href="#">Click here to fetch HTML content</a></p>
        <p><a id="default" href="#">Reset</a></p>
        </div>

            <div id="result"></div>
</body></html>      




<!-- jQuery Code -->

            $(function(){

                $('#switcher a').click(function(event){
                    var bodyClass = this.id.split('-')[1];

                    $('body').removeClass().addClass('bodyClass');

                    switch(bodyClass){
                        case 'switcher':
                            $('#result').load('content.html #content');
                            break;
                        case 'switcher-b':
                            $('#result').load('content-b.html #content');
                            break;
                        case 'switcher-c':
                            $('#result').load('content-c.html #content');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $('#result').unload();
                    }
                    return false;
                });

            });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#switcher a').click(function(event){
                    var bodyClass = this.id;

                    $('body').removeClass().addClass('bodyClass');

                    switch(bodyClass){
                        case 'switcher':
                            $('#result').load('content.html #content');
                            break;
                        case 'switcher-b':
                            $('#result').load('content-b.html #content');
                            break;
                        case 'switcher-c':
                            $('#result').load('content-c.html #content');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $('#result').unload();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
```

Just remove `.split('-')[1]` You are taking just a second part of id, after "-" and than testing for full id. Of course it will always to default

Comment: When I remove the .split('-')[1]; the script only works for anchor "id="switcher" but anchors "id="switcher-b" and "id=switcher-c" do not work.

Comment: @user1584751. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KGsyg/) jsfiddle. It shows correct alerts. In Chrome. Check network pane in Firebug(FF) or Inspector (Chrome) and take a look if requests are sent correctly. Possibly there is a problem with html file b and c. Also, you have one ID(switcher) for div and a tags. ID must be unique. This may possibly cause problem in some browsers.

Comment: you were correct there was an issue with html files b and c. Html files b, c, and content are now loading however default is not unloading the loaded html from <div id="result"></div>...

Comment: I used .html('') which does remove the loaded html files, however is this the best way?

Comment: yes. That is Ok. Also you may use `.empty`. Sorry, I did not pay attention that there is `unload` which actually is to bind unload event handler

Comment: Is it possible to place <p><a id="default" href="#">Reset</a></p> in my html file b, c and or content and use either .html('') or .empty() to unload the loaded html from <div id="result"></div>?

Comment: Yes. But you will need to use `.live` (old jquery) or `.on` (latest versions) to put a click handler on your #default. Or you will need to bind a click after each `.load`

Answer (score 0):

Your element a its inside p element

```
$('#switcher p a').click(function(event){});
```

You also can do something like

```
$('a[id^=switcher ]').click(function(event){});
```

Comment: Do not confuse people. that would be a problem in case of `$('#switcher > a')` Space tell jquery to search all children tree, not only the first level (like ">" do)